# Buttons on the android list

Tags: android, android-layout

How i can make buttons from ImageView icon and icon2? then i setOnClickListener on these it doesn't work.. then i click on icon it show what i press the all list item.

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="1.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight=".1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon" />

        <LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/label"
                    android:text="KLIENTO PAVADINIMAS" />

                <ImageView 
                    android:background="@drawable/crown"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label2"
                android:text="KODAS"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight=".9" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon2" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do you set listener on these buttons?

Comment: Like this: imgButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
 imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pressed first icon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 });

Comment: I earsed all layout params because code too long..

Answer (score 2):

> [android:clickable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aclickable)
>   Defines whether this view reacts to click events.

Answer (score 0):

What is it in your xml? Use [Custom ListView](http://www.technotalkative.com/tag/android-custom-listview-example/).